# How to compare values in a data frame in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

say A is a data frame representing how data of all the countries in Olympics game.

I am trying to print data of all the countries that has max of : (summer_gold - winter_gold)/count of total gold.

Please check my code and let me what i am doing wrong here.

```
def answer_three():
    count=A['Gold'].count() + A['Gold.1'].count()  #Gold is no. of summer gold & Gold.1 is winter gold
    X=(((A['Gold']-A['Gold.1']).abs())/count).max() 
    Y=A.where(((A['Gold']-A['Gold.1'].abs())/count).max() == X)
    return Y
answer_three()
```

Error i am getting is :

```
"Array conditional must be same shape as self"
```

Comment: Hi, welcome! Please, provide input data, a reproducible piece of code and the output data you'd like to reach. Otherwise it's impossible to help. Thanks!

Comment: please provide a example of your dataframe and your expected output